# Creating li element from input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have value from `<input type="number">`. How to create li elements same quantity as value?

For example there is input with number of persons, need to create so many `li` elements as person entered.

Comment: what did you try ? show some code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6hog9wyq/ You should try by yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).on('click','#create',function() {
  var liNum = $('#liNum').val();
  if (liNum && !isNaN(liNum)) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    for(var i = 0;i < liNum; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = "List item #" + i;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="liNum" type="number" />
<button id="create">Create list</button>
```